# How can I get char* using lua ffi

Tags: lua, ffi, kong, openresty, luajit

I want to use `luajit ffi` to call `c` function. Now I have a function in `so` file, this function assigns a value to a `char*`, such as this:

```
typedef struct MyStruct_s {
    int a;
}MyStruct;
void *init(char* host, int timeout) 
{
    void *handle = (void*)malloc(MyStruct);
    if(handle == NULL) {
        printf("create myStruct falied\n");
    }

    return handle;
}
int get_value(void *handle, char *buffer, int *len) // I want to get buffer to lua
{
    MyStruct* my_handle = (MyStruct*)handle;
    // my_handle do something
    if(buffer == NULL) {
        printf("buffer is NULL\n");
        return -1;
    }
    char tmp[10] = "hi there";
    memcpy(buffer, tmp, strlen(tmp));
    *len = strlen(tmp);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I get buffer value in lua? I tried this

```
local zkclient = ffi.load("zkclient")   
ffi.cdef [[
void *init();
int get_value(void *zkhandle, char *buffer, int *len);
]]
local handle = zkclient.init()
if handle == nil then
    kong.log.info("handle is nil ")
    return nil
end

local node_value = ffi.new('char[1024]', {0})  // is it right to do this?
local len = 1024;
local node_len = ffi.cast("int *", len)
local node_exist = zkclient.get_value(handle, node_value, node_len)
```

but it do not work, how can I get `buffer` from `get_value` to `lua`?

Comment: What should Lua do with `char* buffer` variable after receiving it? Lua can not operate with C pointers.  Such pointer is only useful for other FFI functions.  Who should be the owner or the memory block pointed to by `buffer`?  Should this memory block be a Lua garbage-collectable item?  Do you want to receive a Lua string instead of C pointer `buffer`?

Comment: If `buffer` is consumed later by some FFI function then what `ctype` should it be compatible with?

Comment: What datatype you want `buffer` value to be converted to on Lua side? (it depends on how you want to use it later)

Comment: @ESkri Do you mean this, `char* get_value(void *handle, int *len)
{
    char *tmp = malloc(*len);
    memcpy(buffer, tmp, strlen(tmp));
    *len = strlen(tmp);

    return tmp;
}` and in lua `ffi.string(get_value)`, but when I `delete` the memory as I have used `malloc`?

Comment: What you want to do with `buffer` in Lua?  What does it need for?

Comment: I use it to  do a legitimacy check, on lua side I use it as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an array instead of a pointer of the same datatype.

```
local function zk_get_value()  -- returns Lua string
   local node_value = ffi.new('char[?]', 1024)
   local node_len = ffi.new('int[1]', 1024)
   zkclient.get_value(handle, node_value, node_len)
   return ffi.string(node_value, node_len[0])   
end
```